# Read Very Large xml file in R from Transport Simulation Outcome

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, bigdata, data-analysis

I have an xml file which is about 20GB from the outcome of a transport simulation software. The XML data looks something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<events version="1.0">
    <event time="10998.0" type="actend" person="pv_car_5315_9162_1" link="link36" actType="home"  />
    <event time="10998.0" type="departure" person="pv_car_5315_9162_1" link="link36" legMode="car"  />
    <event time="10998.0" type="PersonEntersVehicle" person="pv_car_5315_9162_1" vehicle="pv_car_5315_9162_1"  />
    <event time="10998.0" type="coldEmissionEvent" linkId="link36" vehicleId="pv_car_5315_9162_1" CH4="0.08123456"  />
    <event time="10998.0" type="vehicle enters traffic" person="pv_car_5315_9162_1" link="link36" vehicle="pv_car_5315_9162_1" networkMode="car" relativePosition="1.0"  />
    <event time="10999.0" type="left link" link="link36" vehicle="pv_car_5315_9162_1"  />
    <event time="10999.0" type="entered link" link="link65" vehicle="pv_car_5315_9162_1"  />
    <event time="11021.0" type="warmEmissionEvent" linkId="link65" vehicleId="pv_car_5315_9162_1" CO="0.07734376800000001" CO2_TOTAL="62.389434800000004" FC="20.239834596" HC="0.004187986" NMHC="0.0021681760000000004" NOx="0.1196987988" NO2="0.0373424708" PM="0.0011292424" SO2="3.03102E-4" FC_MJ="0.8570199968000001" CO2_rep="58.54285888000001" CO2e="59.168261720000004" PM2_5="0.0011292424" PM2_5_non_exhaust="0.005600000000000001" PM_non_exhaust="0.010399999600000001" BC_exhaust="6.607388E-4" BC_non_exhaust="5.600000000000001E-4" Benzene="1.27142E-4" PN="1.135524E12" Pb="0.0" CH4="0.0020198092" N2O="0.0019291828" NH3="0.0057024384"  />
    <event time="11021.0" type="left link" link="link65" vehicle="pv_car_5315_9162_1"  />
    <event time="11021.0" type="entered link" link="link52" vehicle="pv_car_5315_9162_1"  />
    <event time="11036.0" type="warmEmissionEvent" linkId="link52" vehicleId="pv_car_5315_9162_1" CO="0.038671884000000004" CO2_TOTAL="31.194717400000002" FC="10.119917298" HC="0.002093993" NMHC="0.0010840880000000002" NOx="0.0598493994" NO2="0.0186712354" PM="5.646212E-4" SO2="1.51551E-4" FC_MJ="0.42850999840000004" CO2_rep="29.271429440000006" CO2e="29.584130860000002" PM2_5="5.646212E-4" PM2_5_non_exhaust="0.0028000000000000004" PM_non_exhaust="0.0051999998000000006" BC_exhaust="3.303694E-4" BC_non_exhaust="2.8000000000000003E-4" Benzene="6.3571E-5" PN="5.67762E11" Pb="0.0" CH4="0.0010099046" N2O="9.645914E-4" NH3="0.0028512192"  />
    <event time="11036.0" type="left link" link="link52" vehicle="pv_car_5315_9162_1"  />
    <event time="11036.0" type="entered link" link="link25" vehicle="pv_car_5315_9162_1"  />
    <event time="11046.0" type="warmEmissionEvent" linkId="link25" vehicleId="pv_car_5315_9162_1" CO="0.038671884000000004" CO2_TOTAL="31.194717400000002" FC="10.119917298" HC="0.002093993" NMHC="0.0010840880000000002" NOx="0.0598493994" NO2="0.0186712354" PM="5.646212E-4" SO2="1.51551E-4" FC_MJ="0.42850999840000004" CO2_rep="29.271429440000006" CO2e="29.584130860000002" PM2_5="5.646212E-4" PM2_5_non_exhaust="0.0028000000000000004" PM_non_exhaust="0.0051999998000000006" BC_exhaust="3.303694E-4" BC_non_exhaust="2.8000000000000003E-4" Benzene="6.3571E-5" PN="5.67762E11" Pb="0.0" CH4="0.0010099046" N2O="9.645914E-4" NH3="0.0028512192"  />
</events>
```

What I want is very simple: the only useful information for me is those that type is `warmEmissionEvent`, and I want to have a data frame which shows each line the time, linkID, CO and CO2Total value.

The problem is that this will be a very large XML file (20GB), so my laptop will die with the code below:

```r
library(xml2)

# Define the path to your MATSim emission event XML file
xml_file <- "output5.emission.events.offline.xml"

# Read the XML file
doc <- read_xml(xml_file)

# Extract the 'event' nodes with type 'warmEmissionEvent'
emission_events <- xml_find_all(doc, ".//event[@type='warmEmissionEvent']")

# Create empty lists to store the extracted data
event_time <- vector()
link_id <- vector()
vehicle_id <- vector()
CO <- vector()
CO2_total <- vector()

# Iterate over each 'event' node
for (event in emission_events) {
  # Extract the values of the desired attributes
  event_time <- c(event_time, as.numeric(xml_attr(event, "time")))
  link_id <- c(link_id, xml_attr(event, "linkId"))
  vehicle_id <- c(vehicle_id, xml_attr(event, "vehicleId"))
  CO <- c(CO, as.numeric(xml_attr(event, "CO")))
  CO2_total <- c(CO2_total, as.numeric(xml_attr(event, "CO2_TOTAL")))
}

# Create a data frame with the extracted data
emission_data <- data.frame(
  event_time = event_time,
  link_id = link_id,
  vehicle_id = vehicle_id,
  CO = CO,
  CO2_total = CO2_total
)
```

I tried some methods online, but they are not working really well :(

Do you maybe have a better solution for this? Or maybe some other tools that I can use to analyse the data?

Comment: Perhaps the `ff` package can help you (https://cran.r-project.org/package=ff), or you can have a look at the `arrow` - Package (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/). Both are generally made to handle larger-than-RAM-datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it sounds like you don't have enough memory to read the entire file into memory at one time other options are needed.
Since you are looking to extract information from individuals lines it simplifies the requirements.
A possible options is to read in chunks of data, filter for "warmEmissionEvent", process and save the data before moving to the next chunk.

Maybe this will work:

```
library(stringr)

read_only =4

output <- lapply(seq(0, 16, read_only), function(skip_n) {
   myfile <- read.csv(file='xml_file', skip=skip_n, nrow=read_only)
   warmemission <- myfile[grep("warmEmissionEvent", myfile[,1]), ]
   
   time     <- str_extract(warmemission, "(?<=time=)[0-9.]*")
   linkID   <- str_extract(warmemission, "(?<=linkId=)[0-9.]*")
   CO       <- str_extract(warmemission, "(?<=CO=)[0-9.]*")
   CO2Total <- str_extract(warmemission, "(?<=CO2_TOTAL=)[0-9.]*")

   data.frame(time, linkID, CO, CO2Total)
   #maybe write df to different files to save intermediate steps  
})
dplyr::bind_rows(output)
```

Yes, it is a bit of brute force using str_extract, but with only 4 pieces of data, not worth my effort to get xml2 working.

Of course you will want to read in larger chunks instead of 4 lines at a time.
The sequence with need to end on the number of lines in your file and not 16.   If you try reading pass the end of the file you will like generate an error and will need to try again, thus the recommendation to write the output from each chunk to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Often with huge XML you will get out of memory. Solution is to use XmlReader.  Here is a power shell script that will take huge xml and output your data as csv

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$xmlFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$csvFilename = 'c:\temp\test.csv'

$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($csvFilename)

$writer.WriteLine('time,linkID,CO,CO2Total')

$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($xmlFilename)
While(-not $reader.EOF)
{
    if($reader.Name -ne 'event')
    {
        $reader.ReadToFollowing('event') | out-null;
    }
    if(-not $reader.EOF)
    {
        $event = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement][System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($reader);
        $type = $event.Attribute('type').Value
        if($type -eq 'warmEmissionEvent')
        {
           $time = $event.Attribute('type').Value
           $linkId = $event.Attribute('linkId').Value
           $CO = $event.Attribute('CO').Value
           $CO2Total = $event.Attribute('CO2_TOTAL').Value
           $writer.WriteLine([string]::Join(',',@($time,$linkId,$CO,$CO2Total)))
        }
    }
}
$writer.Flush()
$writer.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the older `XML` package with its SAX API method, [**`xmlEventParse`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/XML/versions/3.98-1.16/topics/xmlEventParse), to read the XML iteratively or in stream tag by tag rather than reading the entire large document into memory at once.

Below builds a CSV of all `event` tags with condition `type="warmEmissionEvent"`, retrieves a subset of sibling attributes, and finally reads in the final CSV:

```r
library(XML)

# INITIALIZE EMPTY CSV WITH HEADERS
csv <- "/path/to/Output.csv"
fileConn <- file(csv); 
writeLines(paste0("time,linkID,vehicleId,CO,CO2Total"), fileConn) 
close(fileConn)

# ITERATIVELY APPEND ROWS TO CSV
doc <- "/path/to/Input.xml"
output <- xmlEventParse(
  doc,
  handlers = list(
    startElement=function(name, attrs){
      
      if("type" %in% names(attrs)) {
        if(attrs["type"] == "warmEmissionEvent") {
          write.table(
            data.frame(
              time = attrs["time"],
              linkId = attrs["linkId"],
              vehicleId = attrs["vehicleId"],
              CO = attrs["CO"],
              CO2_TOTAL = attrs["CO2_TOTAL"]
            ),
            file = csv,
            append = TRUE,
            sep = ",",
            row.names = FALSE,
            col.names = FALSE
          )
        }
      }
    }
  ),
  useTagName=FALSE, 
  addContext=FALSE
)

# READ IN FINAL CSV
warmEmissionEvents <- read.csv(csv)

warmEmissionEvents
#    time linkID          vehicleId         CO CO2Total
# 1 11021 link65 pv_car_5315_9162_1 0.07734377 62.38943
# 2 11036 link52 pv_car_5315_9162_1 0.03867188 31.19472
# 3 11046 link25 pv_car_5315_9162_1 0.03867188 31.19472
```